# npm ERR! Unexpected end of input at 1:379680

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I recently installed the latest version of nodejs i.e v8.1.3 and I am using windows 10

After that, i wanted to install the cordova and ionic packages so I ran the command

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

after running this command I am getting the below error! I am fed up as this error isn't available in Google search also yet.

**This is the error log I am getting on the cmd console**

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input at 1:379680
npm ERR! .1","osenv":"~0.1.3","path-is inside":"~1.0.1","read":"~1.0.7","read-
npm ERR!                                                                      ^                                                           
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SYS73M CR4CK3R\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-10T13_45_29_711Z-debug.log
```

Pls, help _/_

Comment: Do you get the same error when installing other packages? If so, there may be a major bug in ionic/cordova (though unlikely). Try `npm install -g jquery`, for instance.

Comment: yups i also get the same error while installing other packages too

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling node/npm and reinstalling it?

Comment: i have uninstalled before this 4 times this time when i installed the installed i am facing this issue!

Comment: Try versions 8.1.0 to 8.1.2. If those work, there may be a breaking change in 8.1.3 and you might want to open an issue on GitHub as others may begin to have similar bugs.

Comment: @Lansana i have uninstalled the whole nodejs node the specific packages

Comment: @Lansana how to change the version

Comment: You can't "change" the version, but you can uninstall and install a specific version instead of latest. If you are using MacOS, just `brew uninstall node` `brew install node@8.1.0`, etc.

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav try clearing npm cache using "npm cache clean" and try again

Answer (score 9):

What solved it for me was running

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: Same issue for me. I think it was caused by attempting to run `npm install` with a poor connection and attempting to run it again later.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem. But after you run this command you may face a new error `npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY` so in addition to this command I also had to upgrade `npm`. So If anyone still facing the same problem you can try the following:

-Upgrade npm: `npm i -g npm`
-Delete `node_modules` folder
-clean `npm cache`: `npm cache clean --force`
-Re-run `npm install`

Source: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16861

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

This happens mostly due to poor internet connection.
fix your internet issues then run
`npm cache clean --force`
and then run
`npm install -g ionic cordova`

Answer (score 1):

"Unexpected end of input" means can not download file,use "npm config set registry https://registry.npm.xxxxx.org " change the mirroring adress.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, and fixed with @Thomas' idea.

I think you should read the debug.log, mine has a lot of "http fetch GET 304 https://xxxxxxx (from cache)" in it, so it seems like something wrong with npm cache.