# ionic 3 npm install error

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, npm-install, ionic3

I'm getting the following error when i run "`npm install`" inside my ionic project. I didn't get this error earlier.
 I even tried creating a new application using "`ionic start myApp blank`" command.
 Even then i get the same error while `npm install` is runing.

 Please advice, is this due to something broken at ionic end, or could it be a fault in my pc?

 By the way I'm using ionic 3.

```
npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object-keys
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input at 1:19096
npm ERR! ctories":{},"dist":{"shasum":"518f921aeb0560aec7dcab2990b14cf6f3cce5d
```

Comment: Try to re-install your object-keys package.

Comment: could be a problem with the npm (node) version. specifically node 8 with npm 5 doesn't work properly with ionic.

Comment: Was that the total output? Something similar going on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013758/npm-err-unexpected-end-of-input-at-1379680 - in their output it said a complete log is here:.... If you are getting messages like that, have a look at the logs to see if if clues you in

Answer (score 1):

Try "sudo npm install -g ionic"